# Ansible - Replace a dictionary key with the value of another key in the dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
    "some_dict": [
        {
            "ips": [
                "10.10.11.20",
                "10.10.11.21"
            ],
            "id": "11111aaaaa"
        },
        {
            "ips": [
                "10.10.11.22",
                "10.10.11.23"
            ],
            "id": "22222bbbbb"
        },
        {
            "ips": [
                "10.10.11.25",
                "10.10.11.24"
            ],
            "id": "33333ccccc"
        },
        {
            "ips": [
                "10.10.11.26",
                "10.10.11.27"
            ],
            "id": "44444ddddd"
        }
    ]
```

I need to re-work this so that the value of *id* becomes the key to the IP's
that is replace "ips" with the id value

```
"some_dict": [
    {
        "11111aaaaa": [
            "10.10.11.20",
            "10.10.11.21"
        ]
    },
    {
        "22222bbbbb": [
            "10.10.11.22",
            "10.10.11.23"
        ]
    },
    {
        "33333ccccc": [
            "10.10.11.25",
            "10.10.11.24"
        ]
    },
    {
        "44444ddddd": [
            "10.10.11.26",
            "10.10.11.27"
        ]
    }
]
```

using a json_query and jmespath I get the following

```
- name: do something good
  set_fact:
    something_good: "{{ dict(some_dict|json_query(member_id_local_ips)) }}"
  vars:
    member_id_local_ips: >
      [].[member_id,local_ip|[]]
- debug: var=something_good|dict2items
```

This returns the following

```
    "something_good|dict2items": [
        {
            "key": "11111aaaaa",
            "value": [
                "10.10.11.20",
                "10.10.11.21"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "22222bbbbb",
            "value": [
                "10.10.11.22",
                "10.10.11.23"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "33333ccccc",
            "value": [
                "10.10.11.25",
                "10.10.11.24"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "44444ddddd",
            "value": [
                "10.10.11.26",
                "10.10.11.27"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I would however prefer to remove the "key" and "value" keywords if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, some_dict is actually a list of dictionaries. Each item is a dictionary with two keys, "ips" and "id"; each has a value, one as a string and one as a list of strings. If you don't want to convert it to a dictionary first, one way to transform it is to iterate over the current list and create a new list in any new form that you wish.

```
- name: Replace some_dict key with id
  set_fact:
    some_list: "{{ some_list | default([]) + [{ item.id: item.ips }] }}"
  loop: "{{ some_dict }}"

- debug:
    var: some_list

TASK [iis_0.0.1 : debug] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "some_list": [
        {
            "11111aaaaa": [
                "10.10.11.20",
                "10.10.11.21"
            ]
        },
        {
            "22222bbbbb": [
                "10.10.11.22",
                "10.10.11.23"
            ]
        },
        {
            "33333ccccc": [
                "10.10.11.25",
                "10.10.11.24"
            ]
        },
        {
            "44444ddddd": [
                "10.10.11.26",
                "10.10.11.27"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a list, not a dictionary. Let's call it this way

```yaml
  some_list:
    - id: 11111aaaaa
      ips: [10.10.11.20, 10.10.11.21]
    - id: 22222bbbbb
      ips: [10.10.11.22, 10.10.11.23]
    - id: 33333ccccc
      ips: [10.10.11.25, 10.10.11.24]
    - id: 44444ddddd
      ips: [10.10.11.26, 10.10.11.27]
```

- To convert the list to a dictionary use the filter *items2dict*

```yaml
  some_dict: "{{ some_list|items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='ips') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  some_dict:
    11111aaaaa: [10.10.11.20, 10.10.11.21]
    22222bbbbb: [10.10.11.22, 10.10.11.23]
    33333ccccc: [10.10.11.25, 10.10.11.24]
    44444ddddd: [10.10.11.26, 10.10.11.27]
```

- But, you said you want a list again

```yaml
  some_dict:
    - 11111aaaaa: [10.10.11.20, 10.10.11.21]
    - 22222bbbbb: [10.10.11.22, 10.10.11.23]
    - 33333ccccc: [10.10.11.25, 10.10.11.24]
    - 44444ddddd: [10.10.11.26, 10.10.11.27]
```

You can get this by creating lists from the items and mapping the function *items2dict*

```yaml
  some_dict: "{{ some_list|json_query('[].[@]')|
                 map('items2dict', key_name='id', value_name='ips') }}"
```

- If you can't create a pipe there is always the brute-force Jinja option. The expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  some_dict: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in some_list %}
    - {{ i.id }}: {{ i.ips }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    some_list:
      - id: 11111aaaaa
        ips: [10.10.11.20, 10.10.11.21]
      - id: 22222bbbbb
        ips: [10.10.11.22, 10.10.11.23]
      - id: 33333ccccc
        ips: [10.10.11.25, 10.10.11.24]
      - id: 44444ddddd
        ips: [10.10.11.26, 10.10.11.27]

    some_dict: "{{ some_list|items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='ips') }}"
    some_dic2: "{{ some_list|json_query('[].[@]')|
                   map('items2dict', key_name='id', value_name='ips') }}"
    some_dic3: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in some_list %}
      - {{ i.id }}: {{ i.ips }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: some_dict|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: some_dic2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: some_dic3|to_yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I especially like the json_query option but, the solution provided below by Danielle works better for me in this instance